# Idea debugger don't work (or stop?) with Meteor app

Tags: debugging, meteor, intellij-idea

I use Intellij Idea 2017.2 for a Meteor project. Debug starts without any problems, but it ignores all breakpoints and works like simple Run.
OS: Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: did you mute your breakpoints ? this is the option on left side of debugger window.

Comment: No, it's a new project, I have not done any debugger settings in Idea

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue unfortunately, please follow [WEB-25102](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25102) for updates

Comment: Can't figure out how update, there is said no fixes available.